# How to pass variant to double array VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

My idea was to create a function to pass double arrays like this:

```
Function pass(a() As Double, b() as double) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
ReDim a(0 To UBound(b, 1), 0 To UBound(b, 2))
    For i = 0 To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(a, 2)
            a(i, j) = b(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

such that one could use:

```
pass(a,b)
```

and then a=b.

```
a=b
```

doesn't work.. (oh god I miss matlab..)

OK, back to the problem:

This works fine for two double arrays but if I get a variant, and as I use this I can get a variant, this doesn't work. So is there a solution for passing variant values to double arrays? The data is structured like a double array but has not the type double().

Comment: You are probably looking for this
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm
Search for CopyArray

Comment: @storax yeah pretty much what I was looking for, but it doesn't work for me. I copy a variant into a doubl() array both 2D and the output boolean is false, so the function doesn't work for them.

Comment: VBA be like: a=variant ... NOPE don't know what you mean.. range=variant .. perfectly fine.. Well that solves the issue for me then. Since I need to put it into a range anyway. But the question stays open since it hasn't been answered properly..

Comment: *"the output boolean is false"* Ehm, I think you misunderstood something, the output of `Function pass` is always `False` because you didn't return anything in that function. You must set `pass = True` in that function to make it return `True`. You must tell the function *what* it should return, otherwise it cannot know what to return.

Comment: @PEH i was talking abput the copyarray function storax was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this I would remove the types of the parameters.

```
Sub test()

Dim VarArry(0 To 4, 0 To 4) As Variant
Dim DblArry(0 To 4, 0 To 4) As Double
Dim VarAssing() As Variant
Dim DblAssing() As Double
Dim c As Boolean

VarArry(0, 1) = 34
DblArry(0, 1) = 34

c = pass(VarAssing, VarArry)
Debug.Print (TypeName(VarAssing))
Debug.Print (VarAssing(0, 1))

c = pass(VarAssing, DblArry)
Debug.Print (TypeName(VarAssing))
Debug.Print (VarAssing(0, 1))

c = pass(DblAssing, VarArry)
Debug.Print (TypeName(DblAssing))
Debug.Print (VarAssing(0, 1))

c = pass(DblAssing, DblArry)
Debug.Print (TypeName(DblAssing))
Debug.Print (VarAssing(0, 1))


End Sub

Function pass(a, b) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
ReDim a(0 To UBound(b, 1), 0 To UBound(b, 2))
    For i = 0 To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(a, 2)
            a(i, j) = b(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

The output was as follows

```
Variant()
 34 
Variant()
 34 
Double()
 34 
Double()
 34
```